# Streaming Push Topics - Could not load Push Topics. Even though APIs are enabled in SF

Tags: rest-api, workbench, streaming-api, pushtopic

I can't seem to get past this error in workbench even though APIs in the org are enabled using the latest or older api version[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below are check points.

- Make sure 'Streaming API', 'Author apex' permission is enabled.
- User must have atleast create/read permission on the PushTopic
  object.

Use [EMP-Connector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_java_client_intro.htm) instead of workbench.